# I'm looking for a substance that can be used as an adhesive, but that will burn without producing any ash

Tags: home-experiment

I need to 'adhese' paper to plastic, but I need the adhesive to be flammable and quick burning, but without producing any ash or too many toxic fumes.

I know this is an absurd question, but does anything like this exist?

Thanks so much

Comment: You may also want to ask it on [DIY.SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

Nitrocellulose(flash paper). Using acetone or something you get a gel. Caution recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nitrocellulose is my 'paper' layer - will the acetone gel thing still work or will it mess up the nitrocellulose paper? Thanks

Comment: Try dampening the plastic with acetone or the gel. You need to test to get the best way to do it.

Comment: It would be nice if you could list the properties / explain why they occur. Not necessary, though :)

Comment: I don't know much. What I told you is from experiments long ago before everything was a terrorist threat.